# Send and receive messages from firebase database through chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed this setup to authenticate my extension with firebase. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

I want to push data and receive messages from the firebase db. I registered on the gcm client app. Not sure how to proceed next.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js) helpful. Specifically take a look at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/database/scripts/main.js

.. it will show you how to go about Firebase architecture in a JS environment like Chrome.